# Warning about flow control in the function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, control-flow

I made a function to check array for negative numbers and then return the value; it takes the `int testArray[]` as first parameter and `int n=14` as array size. I used a for loop to go though the array. I'm using an `if` statement to compare `testArray[i]<0` and I have an `else` statement to print a message that no negative numbers were found. The code compiles with no errors, but I have no output. I get a warning:

`In function 'int countNegative(int*, int)':
 28:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

I suspect that it can be an issue with the way the parameters are passes to the function.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;

    int countNegative(int testArray[],int n);

    int main(){
        int testArray[] = {-2,0,44,12,-45,17,934,-21,67,88,91,1,0,6};
        int n = 14;

        countNegative(testArray,n);

        system("PAUSE");
        //EXIT_SUCCESS;
        return 0;
    }

    int countNegative(int testArray[],int n){
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(testArray[i]<0){
                int index = testArray[i];
                return index;
            }
            else{
                cout << "No Negative Numbers";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your `countNegative` function.

```
int countNegative(int testArray[],int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(testArray[i]<0){
            int index = testArray[i]; // <= You are returning value here, not the index in the array.
            return index;
        }
        else{
            cout << "No Negative Numbers";
            // No return here, should have returned 0 ?
        }
    }
    // No return here ?
}
```

From the function name, it looks like it is going to count the negative values in the `testArray` and return the total number of negative values.

Why are you getting this warning ?

This is because, let's say there are no negative numbers in `testArray`. In such a case you do not return anything, i.e. your control can reach your else statement as well without any return value. The control may also reach the end of your function without returning any value from there. Since you have marked return type as int, you must return an integer value in all these conditions.

If what I understand is correct, you should refactor your function to just iterate the array and count the total number of negative entries. Finally, you can return that value.

```
    int countNegative(int testArray[],int n){
        int total_negatives = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(testArray[i]<0){
                total_negatives++;
            }
        }
        if (total_negatives == 0)  cout << "No Negative numbers\n";
        return total_negatives;
    }
```

[complete-program](http://ideone.com/lTgHu1)

Answer (score 0):

You should have an int variable to receive your return value from your function call. Your code as written will only return the first index of the first negative number found in your array. If you wanted a count of negative numbers then you shouldn't return right away. Also, if your array ends up having no negative values then you never return anything , you would only be printing out the message that there are no negative values, and you would end up printing that for every item in your array the way things are written.

I would re-write it like this. This function will return the count of negative numbers found in the array or 0 if no negative numbers were found.

```
int countNegative(int testArray[],int n){
    int negs = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(testArray[i]<0){
            negs++;
        }
    }

    return (negs);

}
```

And then you should change your main function like this.

```
int main(){
    int testArray[] = {-2,0,44,12,-45,17,934,-21,67,88,91,1,0,6};
    int n = 14;
    int foundNegatives = countNegative(testArray,n);
    if ( ! foundNegatives ) {
         cout << "No Negative Numbers";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    //EXIT_SUCCESS;
    return 0;
}
```